# Avoid "could not find parserDetail.ini" warning

Tags: perl, xml-simple

When using `XML::Simple`, I always get the warning

```
could not find ParserDetails.ini in /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/XML/SAX
```

I would like do do something like

```
{
no warning qw(insert_your_magic_here);
my $hash_ref = XMLin('my_file.xml')
}
```

I red perldoc about warning http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html and found a 'Cathegory hiearchy' but I do not know in which category is this warning.

Do you know it?

May you know what are those ParserDetail intented for?

Comment: Don't do this. Warnings are there for a reason. Either fix the problem, or just use a different XML parser. I'd suggest XML::Twig as an option.

Comment: In fact, I do not even know what are those parser details for.  Ignorance is bad!

Comment: http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/#parserdetails.ini

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite its name, [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) is extremely difficult to get working correctly, and you would be much better off using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) instead.

`XML::Simple` is warning you that there is no useable SAX parser configuration. Since [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser) is faster and more reliable than the SAX options, I suggest you tell `XML::Simple` to use it instead. You can do this by adding

```
$XML::Simple::PREFERRED_PARSER = 'XML::Parser';
```

to the top of your program, right after `use XML::Simple`.

You may also have to install `XML::Parser`, as it isn't one of the pre-installed core modules.

Comment: Yes, indeed, XML::Simple is for application where the exact form of the XML is not important...